# xSocket WebRTC Sample error

Tags: asp.net, webrtc, xsockets.net

Hi i have a problem i have a aplication that i m desenvolving an its the same princepel like facebook like a social engine in mvc 4 i am trying to put video-conference i already tried in a empty asp.net mvc4 empty internet application and it works xSocket.net WebRTC Sample so where is my error

so i followed the steps  PM> Install-Package XSockets.Sample.WebRTC
1: Add a new XSockets.Web.Bootstrapper (ctrl+shift+a)
2: Under the "Web" tab go to the "Servers" section and set Use Visual Studio Development Server

```
using System.Web;
using XSockets.Core.Common.Socket;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(basicWebRTC.XSocketsWebBootstrapper1), "Start")]

namespace basicWebRTC
{
    public static class XSocketsWebBootstrapper1
    {
        private static IXSocketServerContainer wss;
        public static void Start()
        {
            wss = XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.GetExport<IXSocketServerContainer>(); // when e start An exception of type 'XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Exceptions.ExportException' occurred in XSockets.Plugin.Framework.dll but was not handled in user code //

            wss.StartServers();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Once again. Please provide some more information about what´s wrong or not working

Comment: // when e start An exception of type 'XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Exceptions.ExportException' occurred in XSockets.Plugin.Framework.dll but was not handled in user code //

Comment: I know that, but if you do not provide any more info about what you have done no one will be able to help you!

Comment: I have similar error in my C# Desktop XSockets client application.
I have posted it on XSockets developer forum at following link:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/xsocketsgroup/0IqYrOauKak
Hope someone would help me.